# next.js how to manage global state with context in across multiple layouts

Tags: next.js, global-state

I'm using two layouts in next.js in accordance with per page layout structure.

- One layout for unauthenticated pages
- Another one for authenticated pages

in _app.js

```
import GlobalContext from "../utils/GlobalContext";
....
return getLayout(
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
);
```

in page

```
Login.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
    return (
        <Layout2>
            {page}
        </Layout2>
    )
}
```

global state seems to be reset when visiting a page with different layout.

problem is how to keep global state shared though the context on multiple layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the global state shared among multiple templates we need to wrap the getLayout itself as below

in _app.js

```
return (
    <Layout>
      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </Layout>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is merit in two completely separate shared layouts but will try to address your question. I would create a shared [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and single layout factory that returns the relevant layout based on your rule i.e. user exists etc.

Wrap your Layout in your Context in your _app.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }: MyAppProps) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} key={router.asPath} />
      </Layout>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

Then access context in Layout and render appropriate options:

```
// context
import { useUser } from '../utils/user';

import Header from './header';
import AuthenticatedHeader from './header/authenticated';

interface LayoutProps {
  children: any;
}

const DefaultLayout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

const AuthLayout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedHeader />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

const Layout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
  const { user } = useUser();

  return (
    <>
      {/* conditionally render appropriate  */}
      {user ? <AuthLayout>{children}</AuthLayout> : <DefaultLayout>{children}</DefaultLayout>}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-api-with-multiple-layouts-ueeb3)

Answer (score 1):

In 'my' case... i solved like this in `_app.js`

i place `getLayout()` in context provider.

```
const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)
return (
  <LoginContext.Provider value={value}>
    <DataContext.Provider value={value2}>
      {getLayout(
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  </LoginContext.Provider>
)
```